# iPad icons not being included in build

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcasset

An iPhone app that I inherited responsibility for a long time ago began showing the default icon on Springboard after the upgrade to iOS 11 (and disappeared from App Store searches from iPad).

This is a very old app (last active development was in 2014), and requirements for app icons have changed, so I generated some new icon assets and added them to the project, thinking this and a rebuild would fix any issues.

It didn't.

I've checked the archive that builds, and the icon sizes for the iPad aren't included in the product. I can tell the updated assets are being included, since a bunch of new ones (for example the @3x versions) are included in the build. But the iPad versions (which are included in the .xcassets file and properly assigned) are not.

Does anybody out there have any idea what could be causing this?